# Getting key column in loop + XSLT

Tags: stylesheet

I need a help on getting primary key values repeated times from the xml.Here is the xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request id="test">
<dataSets>
 <dataSet name="dim_table" friendlyName="dim" tableType="DIM">
 <fields>
  <field name="customer_id" dataType="varchar" primaryKey="true"/>
  <field name="customer_name" dataType="VARCHAR" primaryKey="false"/>
  <field name="customer_address" dataType="CHAR" primaryKey="false"/>
 </fields>
 </dataSet>
</dataSets>
</request>
```

the required output is

KeycolumnName,Columnname
customer_id,customer_id
customer_id,customer_name
customer_id,customer_address

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: The example XML does not describe which nodes repeat (which makes a large difference in the XSL required to transform the XML).

Comment: Required output seems confusing.  Is the same customer_id expected on every line of output?  customer_id and customer_name are not available on the same iteration unless you are iterating among "fields" nodes

Comment: Please don't forget to upvote and/or accept answers if they help you (if you have enough reputation to do so).  Thx!

Answer (score 0):

XML formatting is needed for a full answer, but:

```
<xsl:template match="/dataSets/dataSet/fields">
    <xsl:for-each select="field">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

(example code not tested)

Use XPath to define the content of the "select" attributes.

Reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_for-each.asp

Answer (score 0):

Updated code (previous answer couldn't handle this much new code):

This code works for me:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//dataSet">
            <xsl:for-each select="fields/field">
                KeyColumnName="<xsl:value-of select="../field[@primaryKey='true']/@name" />" ColumnName="bar <xsl:value-of select="@name" />"
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Note: The KeyColumnName will be a concatenation of _all_ KeyColumnNames (not just the first one) if there are multiple "field" nodes in the same "fields" node that match [primaryKey='true']

Comment: Thanks a lot David.I got my required output.